# R でパッケージのインストールでエラーが表示されてしまう

Tags: r

パッケージをインストールしようとすると、以下の文が出てきます。
どうすればインストールできるようになるのでしょうか？

**行った手順:**

Rを開く→パッケージ→パッケージのインストール→このメッセージが出てくる
といった流れです。
パッケージの読み込みなどでも同じメッセージが出てきます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
> 警告:   リポジトリー https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib に対する索引にアクセスできません :
> URL 'https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib/PACKAGES' を開けません
> install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) でエラー:
> 引数 "pkgs" がありませんし、省略時既定値もありません

Answer (score 1):

もしかしたらファイアーウォールか、インストールサイトまたはミラーサイトが適切に設定されていないのかもしれません。（一時的に使えないだけかもしれません）

他のサイトの質問で似たような状況があります。参考にされては、どうでしょうか。

- [Rでパッケージがインストールできない問題について - teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/132795)
- [CRAN国内ミラーの使い方](http://www.okadajp.org/RWiki/?CRAN%E5%9B%BD%E5%86%85%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9)、([逐次設定する](http://www.okadajp.org/RWiki/?CRAN%E5%9B%BD%E5%86%85%E3%83%9F%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9#ld036c99))